# Facebook starting behaving weirdly in Safari

Tags: ios, safari, firefox, facebook

For the past three or four days, Facebook will behave reasonably for a few seconds and then will start bouncing all around, maybe a dozen bounces in six or seven seconds. seconds.  I hypothesized that either they or Safari was trying to saving up several new posts and trying to add them (to the top of the page) all at once.  If Facebook is too stupid to specify in advance the size, that would force Safari to rearrange the page as each one loads.  (Because almost every post contains an image.)

So I thought I could turn off WiFi, read what's worth reading, then turn it back on and wait for it to stop thrashing.  But it did the same thing without internet!  It isn't happening for a friend (browser unknown) but it is happening in DuckDuckGo in iPad and Safari on MacBook.  Since neither has updated recently, I suspect that Facebook has added some sort of Javascript that they didn't bother to test on a browser using Apple's webkit.  (I've been told that Apple requires all browsers on IOS to use Webkit for rendering.)

Does that seem like a reasonable conclusion?  Any ideas for mitigation.

UPDATE: Similar behavior on Firefox but far less intense.  One or two bounces in one second and then OK for three or more seconds.

Comment: It does it on my Mac too [Mojave, Safari 14], past few days. Looks like they've changed the page length; it doesn't start until I've scrolled down a little, then you can tell by the scroll thumb that they've suddenly decided to load more data lower down; which always fills the wrong way on FB, forcing what you were reading upwards.

Comment: I guess the only work-around for me is to use Firefox.  On Safari, it makes it impossible for me to use any links that sound worthwhile.  One person told me they're seeing it on Windows.  Another using a Facebook app instead of the web said it was happening there and stopped when she deleted her app and reinstalled it.